# How to access queryParams in a Resolver Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I Need to implement 'search' by passing queryParams through route from the search component to the userList component (example. /search-result?user="Alfred"). Before loading the userList component, i need to make an API call using the queryParams in the userList resolver but the query params keeps showing undefined.

**Search Component**

```
search(searchTerm: string) {
    if (searchTerm) {
      this.router.navigate(['search-result'], { queryParams: { user: searchTerm } });
  }
}
```

**UserList Resolver**

```
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User[]> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  resolve(): Observable<User[]> {
    const searchTerm: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['user'];
    console.log(searchTerm); //Logs Undefined

    return this.userService.getUsers(searchTerm);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the `resolve` function is running before the `queryParams` are populated in the url. Try doing it in an `Rxjs` way.

```
import { filter, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User[]> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  resolve(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.route.queryParams.pipe(
      tap(params => console.log(`Params: ${params}`)),
      // wait until params has user in it
      filter(params => !!params['user']),
      tap(params => console.log('after filter')),
      // extract the value of the user param
      map(params => params['user']),
      // switch to a new observable stream once we know the searchTerm
      switchMap(searchTerm => this.userService.getUsers(searchTerm)),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Use the tap operator to debug the stream. See what the log is and make sure `console.log(`Params: ${params}`)` has the user params.

**Edit2**

Try

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/search-result?user=${searchTerm}`);
```

, I am thinking there is something wrong with how you navigate.

**Edit 3**

I am thinking `queryParams` can only be read when the component itself loads and not at the run time of the route resolvers because it is saying, I need to go to the route of `search-result`, give me the data before I go to `search-result` and it is independent of the queryParams. To fix this, I followed this guide (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html).

1.) In `app-routing-module.ts`, change the registration of the path to:

`{ path: 'search-result/:user', component: UserListComponent, resolve: { users: UserResolver } },`

Now the user will be the parameter we are after in the URL.

2.) In `search.component.ts`, change `search` to:

```
search(searchTerm: string) {
    if (searchTerm) {
      this.router.navigate([`search-result/${searchTerm}`]);
    }
  }
```

3.) In `user-resolver.service.ts`, change it to this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User[]> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<User[]> {
    const searchTerm: string = route.paramMap.get('user');

    return this.userService.getUsers(searchTerm);
  }
}
```

I when console logging searchTerm, it is the accurate value. Thanks for providing the StackBlitz, it helped you and me.

Comment: Thank you, but apparently the page no longer navigates from the Search component, any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited the solution, you will have to debug with the `tap` operator.

Comment: log from first tap operator "Params: [object Object]", but doesn't proceed or navigate to the UserList component

Comment: Yea, the filter is stopping it from proceeding any further. Try the new edit I suggested.

Comment: Still the same *sad Emoji*

Comment: :/ Is it possible you make a StackBlitz to reproduce it minimally? You can make `this.userService.getUsers` return an array of observables with maybe a delay and not actually make API calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208691/discussion-between-ojay-and-alif50).

Answer (score 12):

On latest versions of Angular you can get the ActivatedRouteSnapshot on the resolver function.

```
  export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User[]> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  resolve(**route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot**): Observable<User[]> {

    **console.log(route.queryParams)**

    return this.userService.getUsers(searchTerm);
  }
}
```